# How to call a function in jQuery append with C# variable?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to call a function with the value of the selected index of a drop-down menu that returns an array and append the result to my div 'content', but I can't figure how can I make this work? I can't use the variable test in my function.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var test = document.getElementById("drop-down").value
        $("#content").append("<h1>" + @DB.AfficherReponses(test)[0] + "</h1>")
    </script>
}
```

Comment: You need to use ajax to call a server method and return a response (or pass all values of `DB.AfficherReponses` to the view and assign it to a javascript array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `C# Method` value in `JavaScript/jQuery`. But you can't pass `JavaScript/jQuery` value into  `C# Method`.

**Possible:**

```
@{var str="Hi";}

@section Scripts {
    <script>        
        $("#content").append("<h1>'" + @str + "'</h1>")
    </script>
}
```

**Impossible :**

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var test = document.getElementById("drop-down").value
         @DB.AfficherReponses(test)
    </script>
}
```

But you can do by ajax calling.

**Example:**

```
//controller
public class JsonDemoController : Controller  
    {  
        public JsonResult WelcomeNote(string name)  
        {  
           string output = "Welcome " +name;    
            return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
        }  
     }  

//view

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var test = document.getElementById("drop-down").value
         $("#content").append("<h1>'" + getWelcomeNote(test) + "'</h1>")

function getWelcomeNote(name) {
    var json;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/JsonDemo/WelcomeNote/" + anme,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        json = data;
    });
    return json;
}

    </script>
}
```